# How to make a queue faction for my Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message-queue

I've been trying to make a queue faction for my Discord bot. Any ideas on how to make one? This is my play command:

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ["p"])
async def play(ctx, url):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
        'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['url']
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice.is_playing()
        await ctx.send('Bot is playing')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bot is already playing")
        return
```

Comment: Anyway i found a solution thanks for the help

Comment: if you found a solution you should post it as an answer and accept it, so that others can read it if they had the same problem.